# Definition of rational map in Silverman

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am reading Silverman's book the arithmetic of elliptic curves. He defines rational map as follows:

> **Definition.** Let $V_{1}$ and $V_{2} \subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$ be projective varieties. A *rational map from $V_{1}$ to $V_{2}$* is a map of the form
>   $$
> \phi:V_{1}\to V_{2},\quad \phi=[f_{0},\cdots,f_{n}],
> $$
>   where the functions $f_{0},\cdots,f_{n}\in \overline{K}(V_{1})$ have the property that for every point $P\in V_{1}$ at which $f_{0},\cdots,f_{n}$ are all defined, 
>   $$
> \phi(P)=[f_{0}(P),\cdots,f_{n}(P)]\in V_{2}.
> $$

Then he also defines $\phi$ being regular at $P\in V_{1}$:

> **Definition.** A rational map $\phi=[f_{0},\cdots,f_{n}]:V_{1}\to V_{2}$ is *regular at* $P\in V_{1}$ if there is a function $g\in \overline{K}(V_{1})$ such that 
>   (i) each $gf_{i}$ is regular at $P$; (ii) there is some $i$ for which $(gf_{i})(P)\neq 0$.

After this definition, he said: if such a $g$ exists, then we set $\phi(P)=[(gf_{0})(P),\cdots,(gf_{n})(P)]$.

My main question is: (1) if a rational map $\phi=[f_{0},\cdots,f_{n}]:V_{1}\to V_{2}$ is regular at $P$, do we have $[(gf_{0})(P),\cdots,(gf_{n})(P)]\in V_{2}$? Why?

This is probably true based on the definition of isomorphism of varieties. But I want to know why. I also want to make sure I understand the definitions correctly.

(2) If I want to check $[f_{0},\cdots,f_{n}]$ is a rational map, I just need to check $f_{0},\cdots,f_{n}\in \overline{K}(V_{1})$, and for every $P\in V_{1}$ at which $f_{0},\cdots,f_{n}$ are all defined and $f_{i}(P)\neq 0$ for some $i$, we have $[f_{0}(P),\cdots,f_{n}(P)]\in V_{2}$. Right?

(3) If $\phi$ is a rational map and I want to check $\phi$ is regular at $P\in V_{1}$, I just need to find some $g\in\overline{K}(V_{1})$ such that (i) and (ii) are true. Right? Do I also need to check that $[(gf_{0})(P),\cdots,(gf_{n})(P)]\in V_{2}$?

I ask this because in his proof of proposition 2.1, he only checked (i) and (ii) but did not check $[(gf_{0})(P),\cdots,(gf_{n})(P)]\in V_{2}$. I'm not sure if he skipped it or we don't need to check.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The point $[gf_0(P),\ldots, gf_n(P)]$ is the same as the point $[f_0(P),\ldots, f_n(P)]$, because the coordinates are proportional.

Comment: @danneks If $\phi$ is regular at $P$, then we only have each $gf_{i}$ is regular at $P$, but we don't have each $f_{i}$ is regular at $P$. So $f_{i}(P)$ may not be well defined.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that (1) follows from the fact that as a projective variety $V_2$ is defined as a zero locus of a set of homogeneous polynomials. We could replace $f_0,\ldots, f_n$ with the vector of polynomials gotten by cancelling all the denominators, i.e. multiply by the lcm of the denominators and look at the numerators instead. Then, by Nullstellensatz, those numerators satisfy all the equations defining $V_2$ et cetera. I'm not fully conversant with the details myself.

Comment: (cont'd)  But I want to make a general remark that this chapter is not a very good resource for learning about algebraic varieties. Basically Silverman wants to give a review, and introduce notation used in the rest of the book. See the first paragraph of chapter 1 for recommended references for details like this. This may be a bit unsatisfactory, aggravating even, but IMHO you can take a few facts from algebraic geometry on faith without your understanding of elliptic curves taking any damaging hits. Worked for me, both in the contexts of algebraic groups and elliptic curves.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you.